# Identifying metal post next to a house

Tags: basement, foundation, outdoor, exterior

Next to my house is part of a metal post.  It looks like it has been cut off at the top.  I would like to remove it, but am not sure what it is.  I know it's not a grounding rod, but there is some graffiti or writing on the foundation next to it; I am not sure if it is related.  This is in the American north east.

This is very close to where our water line comes in.

Can anyone identify this and if it is safe to remove?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a cut off T-post (fence post), and IMHO it is a significant hazard, especially to kids and dogs. If a dog steps on it wrong it could slash a foot to the bone.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/T-Post-Post/4758566

If you have a high lift jack or T-post puller you could probably wrap a chain around the post and pull it out. Otherwise just dig it out. Usually these are driven it no more than 1 ft or 18". Usually they have a stabilizing plate parallel to the top of the T cross section.

Comment: If pulling it out proves too difficult, dig down 6-8 inches, cut off the top with a sawz-all. Then drive it in as deep as possible and cover with soil.

Comment: You've got a depression there so fill it with water from a hose.  Dig out the damp soil, then repeat as necessary. The post will come out much easier. If you have a mattock or one of those  steel digging bars you may be able to pry the bar out. There are a lot of ways to get something like this out. It will almost certainly not be deeply buried. Get it out and recycle it; it's good steel.

Comment: This makes sense now, there was probably a fence from the house to the edge of the yard.  Thanks.

Comment: If the water line is near this post, the best thing to do might be to carefully dig it out. Where is the property located?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a stake used by a mason, landscaper, carpenter, or some other craftsman to put up a *level-line*:

[image]

No problem removing it; however it might be difficult. I suspect that is why it is still there, it was hard to pull out so they just cut it off as low to the ground as they could.

p.s.- your welcome for the cool/crude image I stole from the web...